# about if statement in php

Tags: php, html

I know in the if $_post statement I should put the input button ID but nothing seems to work

```
if($_POST['butsave']==1){
                           $name     = $_POST['name'];
                           $email    = $_POST['email'];  
                           $phone    = $_POST['phone'];
                           $city     = $_POST['city'];    
                           $password = $_POST['password'];
                         }

<input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" id="butsave">
```

Comment: before accessing the values using `$_POST` it's always better to check if there's a value that's assigned to the value that you are accessing(using `isset()` function)

Answer (score 1):

Using post method you can access the value by its name not by the id. try isset to check whether the field is available and set in form.

```html
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" id="butsave">
</form>
```

lets assume the below code is submit.php

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{ 
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $email=$_POST['email']; 
 $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
 $city=$_POST['city'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 }
```